# Curl an unresolvable host?

Tags: php, curl, dns

I need to Curl from a PHP website to a host that's unresolvable from the target machine (`curl_error` returns `(6) couldn't resolve host`). It's resolvable just fine on my local machine though, so after some web searching I figured it might be a DNS caching issue.
I only have FTP access to this webserver, so I can't [restart Apache or edit the r.conf file](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10378200-curl-error-Couldn-t-resolve-host&p=10974721&viewfull=1#post10974721).
I tried Curling using the IP address I got from pinging the domain, but unfortunately I need to make requests to a subdomain (e.g., api.domain.com), and requests to the IP address directly get handled differently.

I had hoped I could specify the subdomain+domain in the Host header (see below), but this doesn't work either.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$opt = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://11.22.33.44/handler.php?params=1',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Host: subdomain.domain.com')
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $opt);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this "doesn't work?"

Comment: It doesn't work, as it seems as if the Host header is ignored. I get the same result without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to the Host: fiddling (if you use a new enough PHP version, apparently this is in 5.5 or later) is to pre-populate the libcurl DNS cache with a "fake" entry for the host name and then you can use the host name in the URL.

See the CURLOPT_RESOLVE option which seems badly documented in the PHP docs but can be found out about in the bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63488&edit=1

The underlying libcurl option [CURLOPT_RESOLVE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html) is documented on the curl web site.

Comment: Badly documented indeed, but this looks promising!

Comment: Unfortunately, using CURLOPT_RESOLVE I still get the same Curl error. I used the code snippet on that bug tracker page—once with the subdomain and once without—but neither had any noticeable effect.

Comment: Then investigate exactly how the request looks like and make sure it is correct, because both these methods should work

Comment: Thanks to that suggestion, I got it to work with the Host: fiddling! Still no idea why CURLOPT_RESOLVE does nothing, but if you hadn't said the Host header should work too, I might have given up! Thank you